# htaccess rule for url not ending with certain words

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, regular-expressions

I need to rewrite few urls if those url not ending with certain words. For example, i need to rewrite following url

```
/category1/subcategory1/aproduct-url-title
to
/category1/fixedword/aproduct-url-title
```

the rewrite should not takes place for the following urls as these are ending with certain specific words(view-all, p10, p20, p30, low-to-high, high-to-low) -

```
/category1/subcategory1/view-all
/category1/subcategory1/p10
/category1/subcategory1/p20
/category1/subcategory1/low-to-high
/category1/subcategory1/high-to-low
```

I've tried with following rule with no success -

```
RewriteRule ^(category1|category2)\/(.*)\/(!p[0-9]+|view-all|low-to-high|high-to-low)$ /$1/fixedword/$3
```

I've tried with following rules too -

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(p[0-9]+|view-all|low-to-high|high-to-low)$
RewriteRule ^(category1|category2)\/(.*)\/(.*)$ /$1/fixedword/$3
```

Appreciate your help.

Thanks

Comment: What version of Apache are you using? You should include that as a tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must perform a negative lookahead and capture.

The correct `RewriteRule` will look something like this:

```
RewriteRule ^(category1|category2)\/(.*)\/((?!p[0-9]+|view-all|low-to-high|high-to-low).*)$ /product/detail/$3
```